# Problems calculating a double integral of a product of functions in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate a double integral with the function "integral2" from the R package "pracma". 
I'm having issues calculating

```
integral2(function(x,y){ X(x)*R(x,y)*X(y) }, 0, 10, 0, 10)
```

where

```
X <- function(t) {
  -0.4*sqrt(2)*sin(pi*1*t)+0.016*sqrt(2)*sin(pi*2*t)-0.01*sqrt(2)*sin(pi*3*t)
}
```

and

```
R <- function(x,y){(1/2*(x^2-x+1/6))*(1/2*(y^2-y+1/6))-
           (1/24*((abs(x-y)^4)-2*(abs(x-y)^3)+(abs(x-y)^2)-1/30))}.
```

My result for the double integral in r is

```
integral2(function(x,y){ X(x)*R(x,y)*X(y) }, 0, 10, 0, 10)$Q = 80.77929,
```

but if I calculate the same integral in Maple, the result is 87.911.

Comment: A piece of evidence that looks bad for integral2:  If you take     `integral2(function(x,y){X(x)*R(x,y)*X(y)},0,5,0,10)$Q + integral2(function(x,y){X(x)*R(x,y)*X(y)},5,10,0,10)$Q`  you get a different answer.

Comment: @G5W  `integral2(function(x,y){X(x)*R(x,y)*X(y)},xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=10)$Q`
is something different than 
`integral2(function(x,y){X(x)*R(x,y)*X(y)},xmin=5,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=10)$Q`.
The integral limits are different.

Comment: I am splitting the integral from x=0 to x=10 into two parts (0,5) and (5,10)  The sum of those two should be the same as the integral (0,10)

Comment: I understand. It's really not good that the results differ

Comment: Could you try splitting it up that way on Maple?

Comment: If I split the integral up that way, the result is 85.67 in Maple. Unsplited it is 87.911.
Looks like the integrand is difficult to integrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work.

```
X <- function(t){-0.4*sqrt(2)*sin(pi*1*t)+0.016*sqrt(2)*sin(pi*2*t)-
    0.01*sqrt(2)*sin(pi*3*t)}

R <- function(x,y){(1/2*(x^2-x+1/6))*(1/2*(y^2-y+1/6))-
    (1/24*((abs(x-y)^4)-2*(abs(x-y)^3)+(abs(x-y)^2)-1/30))}

f <- function(x, y){X(x)*R(x, y)*X(y)}

integral2b <- function(f, lower, upper){
  integrate( function(y) {
    sapply(y, function(y) {
      integrate(function(x) f(x,y), lower[1], upper[1])$value
    })
  }, lower[2], upper[2])
}

integral2b(f, c(0, 0), c(10, 10))
#84.94517 with absolute error < 0.0081
```

See [R-Help](https://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/04/10/5951.html), this answer was adapted from that thread.